# Focus on the first empty input

Tags: javascript, focus, html-input

I am trying to focus the first empty input element on first submit but when the email and password inputs are empty, it always focuses on the password (latter) input first.

How can I focus on the first empty input in a way that works across all browsers?

```
 $('input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
          this.focus();
      }
 });
```

Comment: Try `return false; ` after you set the focus

Comment: its not working. i already tried it. i'm using opera

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are iterating over all input elements and calling `.focus()` if it has no value. If both the username field and the password field have no value, it will first call `.focus()` on the username field, but then it will continue iterating and call `.focus()` on the password field too, which takes focus away from the username field. What you want is to stop iterating over the input fields when you detect the first one with no value. To do this just `return false;` to tell JQuery's each to stop iterating.

```
$('input').each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

For comparison, see this demo:

Your way: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/XbpeMd
With `return false;`: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/VLPMpr

You can see your bug is reproduced in the first demo, and then it's fixed in the second demo. You can load those demos in any browser and see that it works.

Edit: Here it is working in Opera.

[image]

Comment: @sagay_paul Did this end up helping you?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in vanilla JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
for (var i = 0, n = input.length; i < n; i = i + 1) {
  // may also need to test for input[i].type
  if (!input[i].value) {
    input[i].focus();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `return false;` after you focus the element to break the `$.each()` loop. Currently the focus will be set to your *last* empty element as the loop continues.

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Edit, to be clear:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        this.focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Edit, so you won't have to read all the comments:

The complete solution was to use `event.preventDefault()` in the according `onSubmit` handler and then check the inputs for empty values in it.
Afterwards some further processing (as in: validating and finally submitting it to the (server-side) application) of the inputs is needed of course.

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // focus first empty input
    $('#loginForm input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            this.focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // further input processing
});
```

Comment: yeah. i have tried it. i even use `preventDefault` but it's not working. it just refreshes the page because of error

Comment: this wont work. i dont know if its just because of opera. but it really is not working

Comment: no. i mean the error is in my code because the page just refreshes it should not refresh.

Comment: Have you bound a handler on submit?

Comment: Yes, i aleady bind it

Comment: I got it. thanks a lot man. just need a `preventDefault` outside the loop. sorry bout that. thanks a lot, i mean it. :-). here's my code `$('#loginForm').on('submit',function (e){
  
  $('input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
          this.focus();
          return false;
      }
  });

  e.preventDefault();


 });`

Comment: I would have put the `preventDefault` above the `$('input')` section. And don't forget to check the inputs after this loop and submit it to your application.
One more tip: Add IDs or classes to your inputs or wrap them in an appropriate container and don't just iterate over every input on your page. For example: `$('#loginForm > input')`.

Comment: Is there a security if i give each input an id or classes? i'm new to ajax so i need some guidance.

Comment: No, they won't provide any security.
IDs are unique, on each page an ID must only be used once, for examle `#loginForm`, classes can be used on multiple elements and are mainly used for styling via CSS and to add functions via JavaScript to similar elements. Adding IDs or classes in this example would be for convenience and you won't select every input on your page if used correctly. You may have a look at https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ (I haven't read the whole page but it seems to explain the matter quite well).
I also edited my answer, so feel free to accept it.

Comment: yeah. i get it. this is a nice tut. thanks for this. i'm just curios if any hacks or  injections would happen if you don't use id's or classes like at login form or a registration form. i dont really know what are the hacks involved on jquery. over the past month i have used php and learn some securities in it but not js.